# Psql output to file with column alias starting with number

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am running psql from command line and sending output to a file. It is a simple select statement on a view, but I am getting a syntax error when I have a column alias that starts with a number.

I ran the query in PgAdmin and it works (which makes me believe that this is some sort of issue with psql). I also tried adding a '_' to the beginning of the alias and that allows it to go through.

works:   'abc as "_1abc"'

doesn't work:   'abc as "1abc"'

```
psql -u <username> -h <host> -p <port> -d <DB> -o <outputfile> -A -c 
"SELECT abc as "1abc" From example.view
```

This is the error I get:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "1"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a problem with nested double quotes. You need to escape the inner ones.

```
psql -u <username> -h <host> -p <port> -d <DB> -o <outputfile> -A -c "SELECT abc as \"1abc\" From example.view"
```